# Display images with different extension (PHP)

Tags: php, image, mysqli

Below are coding that I currently use to display images from database :

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','demo') or die('Unable To connect');
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM images");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '" />';
}
```

**Problem with those coding :** It only display images with **.png** extension because I am using `echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '" />';` to display it.
**What I am trying to do :** I wanted to display images with extension `.jpeg` `.png` and `.gif` as well.

Is there anybody that can help me with other simple way of displaying images? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the format in the database as well:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','demo') or die('Unable To connect');
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM images");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo '<img src="data:image/' . $row['format'] . ';base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '" />';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi Just get the `image` `extension` and use it

```
$ext = pathinfo($row['image'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo '<img src="data:image/' . $ext . ';base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '" />';
```

Comment: Having to read every image in a loop (Especially with a large amount of images), can cause unnecessary disk IO/CPU cycles.

Answer (score 2):

@FrankerZ already gave correct solution but if you have already stored base64 images on your database it will be problematic to add format column.

You can discover the mime type of image from base64 like that;

```
$img = $row['image']; // base64 of your image 
$fileInfo = finfo_open(); // file info resource 
$mimeType = finfo_buffer($fileInfo, $img, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
```

> If you have already existing records, **do not apply this methodology on your each iteration**. Simply add new column to your database, and fill/update these new colums using this methodology. After that, use @FrankerZ 's solution.

Comment: I added new warning to my post. Please consider it.